# Mapbox gl offline

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to prepare mapboxgl app which works offline, I want to use only javascript engine, local rasters and geojsons. How to avoid connection to mapbox tiles?

```
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'myToken';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'MyStyle.json',  // local style with connection to mapboxstyle. How to avoid it?
center: [-87.61694, 41.86625],
zoom: 15.99,
pitch: 40,
bearing: 20
});

map.on('load', function() {
map.addLayer({
'id': 'room-extrusion',
'type': 'fill-extrusion',
'source': {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': 'myData.geojson'
},
'paint': {

'fill-extrusion-color': ['get', 'color'],
'fill-extrusion-height': ['get', 'height'],
'fill-extrusion-base': ['get', 'base_height'],
'fill-extrusion-opacity': 0.5
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "local style with connection to mapboxstyle"?

Comment: My aim is to build offline app without any underlay from mapbox or OSM, just want to use mapbox library with one or two geojsons with buildings.

Comment: As I understand 
style: 'MyStyle.json' contains information about "how map looks and connection to data stored in mapbox". The first step of my application is to run mapbox engine without any map :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use just an empty style as map option, there is no need for `mapboxgl.accessToken = 'myToken';` :

```
<script>
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: {
        version: 8,
        sources: {},
        layers: []
       },
center: [-87.61694, 41.86625],
zoom: 15.99,
pitch: 40,
bearing: 20
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it's easy now :)